# Where does the PHP file() function get line numbers?

Tags: php, file-io

When I execute the following code, I get output a list of lines from the file, with line numbers.

```
<?php
$lines = file('C:\sm\lines.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Now I would imagine the array returned by `file()` would be a simple one dimensional vector, and I would have to keep a line_num variable in my loop. How do things work here that I get the associative pair `$line_num => $line` for each line in the file?

Comment: Basically do you want to know why you get a numerical array and you can use the foreach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file` is effectively the same as iterating a filepointer and adding each line in the file to an array. You dont get the line numbers, but the regular numeric index in the array.

In other words, `file` does

```
function file($filename) 
{
    $fp = fopen($filename);
    while (!eof($fp)) {
        $lines[] = fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return $lines;
}
```

This is of course simplified. If you want to know the exact details, have a look at

- http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/file.c#706

As for why you can do

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> `foreach (array_expression as $value)`
>   `statement`
>   `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`
>   `statement`
>
> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).
>
> The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key variable on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the line number, it is the index of the entry within the array. In this case its always `$lineNumber = $index + 1`, because `file()`  creates a new index entry for every line

Answer (score 1):

A non-associative array automatically gets assigned numeric array keys, i.e.

```
array(
  0 => 'first item',
  1 => 'second item,
  ...
  9 => 'tenth item',
);
```

So the array key winds up being the line number minus one.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would imagine the array returned by file() would be a simple one
>   dimensional vector, and I would have to keep a line_num variable in my
>   loop

A PHP array is actually an ordered map:

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php